# jQuery get callback not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I'm loading three files:

```
$.when(

    $.get("data/radisson.svg", function(svg){
        console.log("svg");
    }),

    $.get("data/radisson.xml", function(xml){
        console.log("xml");
    }),

    $.get("data/meshes.obj", function(obj){
        console.log("obj");
    })           

).then(function () {
    console.log("Loaded");
});
```

All three files are loading - I can see them in the network tab.  However the console is only showing "svg" and "obj".  "xml" is not being logged - it's like the callback is not being fired after the file is loaded.  Also, the .then callback is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that if the xml file is malformed, the file will load but the callback will fail.  Not what I expected, but at least now I know.